# JPQL - Spring Boot Repository Query - Map Property

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a map property in my domain class and I'm attempting to create a query in the repository or use the default "findByBlah" syntax to pull property from database. Will not work currently. I can easily write the query in SQL but I have no idea what JPQL expects. How can I pull this data from database using JPQL or the interface "findBy" syntax? No matter which repository method I current use, when it pulls the "Collector" from the database, the attribute (map or list of complex object) is always null.

Domain Object:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "collector")
public class Collector {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "collector_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "attribute_name")
    @Column(name = "attribute_value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "collector_attributes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "collector_id"))
    private Map<String, String> attributes;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ObjectUtil.print(this);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface CollectorRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Collector, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select c from Collector c where c.attributes[$1] = $2")
    Page<Collector> findByAttributesNameAndValue(String name, String value, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Here is the query that works in the H2 Console:

```
SELECT * FROM Collector a INNER JOIN collector_attributes b ON a.collector_id = b.collector_id where b.attribute_name= 'nickName' and b.attribute_value  = 'Critikon'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only this is working to me is to define an Object relation instead of a map:

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "COLLECTOR_ATTRIBUTES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTOR_ID"))
    private List<CollectorAttribute> attributes;
```

And the enbedded object

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class CollectorAttribute {

    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE")
    private String value;
}
```

now you can query using properties of embedded object

```
public interface CollectorRepository extends JpaRepository<Collector, Long> {
    List<Collector> findByAttributesKeyAndAttributesValue(String key, String value);
}
```

To retrieve `COLLECTOR_ATTRIBUTES` in select we can define a `@NamedEntityGraph` in `Collector` class and repository method as follows

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Collector.attributes",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("attributes"))
@Entity
@Table(name = "COLLECTOR")
public class Collector {
```

and  report `@EntityGraph` in Repository method

```
public interface CollectorRepository extends JpaRepository<Collector, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Collector.attributes", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Collector> findByAttributesKeyAndAttributesValue(String key, String value);
    }
}
```

Now you have also attributes

If you want to load attributes also on other methods, you have to use `@EntityGraph`

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Collector.attributes", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
Optional<Collector> findById(Long var1);
```

Comment: This answer compiles for me and it persists the objects to the repository however like the above, the collector attribute does not come back when the repository queries. I guess I should have put that in my original response. I'll add that to the description

Comment: Updated answer with `CollectorAttribute` loaded

Comment: I still get a null for the list for some reason. Is this working for you?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenPCM/openpcm-server/tree/integration-test

This is the branch that has this test.
There is an integration test which is failing with null attributes
https://github.com/OpenPCM/openpcm-server/blob/integration-test/src/test/java/org/openpcm/controller/CollectorControllerIntTest.java

method: test_read_byId_happy

Comment: are you trying it locally? in this repo i see `public @ResponseBody Collector readCollector` that is using `repository.findById(id)`. Yes CollectorAttribute are present. Related Attributes must load with `@EntityGraph` defined

Comment: Actually you are right. Your method above works, what is not working is the default repository deserialization. I added a test that actually uses your method (sorry my OP was a bit misleading I'm noticing).
So, when we use the repository method, the attributes are there. But when I use repository.findById(id), I get the object back but that object does not have attributes.

I have updated that branch in github, the test for your repository retrieval works but the test_read_byId_happy does not

Comment: this is because yo have to redefine also findById obviously  `@EntityGraph(value = "Collector.attributes", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<Collector> findById(Long var1);`

Comment: absolutely. Making a few bonehead mistakes, but appreciate it alot. Accepted